# Android Studio macOS Slows Down After Gradle Build

Tags: macos, android-studio, gradle

I've a problem about Android Studio. I don't specify version because I tried it on 3.6.2, 4 Beta 4 and 3.5.3 versions. When I open Studio before building gradle editor is so fast to use, I can get really quick answer all of my actions like copying and pasting code, getting inspection about code and etc., but **after gradle sync** completed Studio starts to freezing when I do any action. That's why I can't use Studio.

I've **endpoint protection, firewalls, secure VPN and etc.** on my computer because it's my work computer. But last month everything was fine, it was super fast. I didn't use this mac for a month, after when I try to work I faced this issue.

Studio's CPU usage always overloaded like **%150**, even when I don't do anything on Studio sometimes. My macOS was Mojave but I upgraded to Catalina to solve this problem but it didn't affect. My co-workers has same computer with **same softwares** but they don't have any problem like this. And last note, when gradle build fail Studio starts to work fast again.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I've found the solution by clean setup of Android Studio 3.5.3 version. Now my Studio works like a charm again! So you need to following rules on terminal first.

```
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/AndroidStudioProjects
rm -Rf ~/.gradle
rm -Rf ~/.android
rm -Rf ~/Library/Android*
```

Then download [Android Studio 3.5.3](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) from the archive, install and here it is!

Comment: be careful it's gonna clear your projects folder too, if you don't need it just don't run that command which is " rm -Rf ~/AndroidStudioProjects "